# Centaurs in an Urban Fantasy

Tags: urban-fantasy, centaur

Okay trying to make this as narrow as possible. I hope.

I have world where magic has returned in modern times. It came back in 2010 but the story takes place in 2018. In this word some people have been changed into non-human or part human beings. Centaurs, Naga, Mermaids etc.

Most Centaurs are normal horse body with a human torso. They weigh as much as a horse. 
 So I'm asking about the mechanics of transportation for a Centaur, the vehicles possible and how a Centaur would control a vehicle. They still use oil and gas for now.

Comment: This is very, very broad...

Comment: Hello Dee, and welcome to Worldbuilding SE. Please take a look at the [Worldbuilding Tour](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/tour) for information on how to write a good and valuable post. Your post is a **Request For Ideas**, or [**Develop My High-concept**](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4868/) post. Those are very well suited for the [Worldbuilding Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17213/the-factory-floor), but not so much Questions & Answers, which is where we are now. To enter the chat, accrue 20 reputation points, and click the link. Welcome. :)

Comment: At the moment, your asking an incredibly broad question that would likely take anywhere from 17 to 50 pages to answer in full. I'd recommend breaking this down into multiple smaller questions so that it can more easily be addressed. Maybe just start with centaurs and transportation? I'd be pretty interested in helping you with that conundrum.

Comment: I think the obvious answer here is "Mustangs" :D

Comment: I would not want to give birth to a centaur, I mean i;m not racist it just sounds painful. In truth though if this is the near future perhaps they simply use driverless cars/horsecarriges depending on their needs?

Comment: Oooh driverless. Humm has potential. It's set in 2018, for the moment they are still using oil and gas. But are looking into the possibility of magic powered vehicles.

Answer (score 11):

**Mustangs!**  No?  Maybe **pony cars?**  Get it, because...no?  Oh alright fine.

It seems like a broad question, but assuming you want something based on current, existing vehicles, your only real option is an up-fitted, high-roof commercial van.

[image: Ram ProMaster commercial van]

Why a commercial van?  For a few main reasons.

1. High roof available to allow the centaur to enter from the back
2. Usually truck-chassis-based, to support the weight
3. Commonly up-fitted for a variety of duties

Your centaur is, assuming normal human and horse sizes, probably 8-9 feet tall and weighs close to a ton.  A normal car is not going to carry 2,000 pounds of driver that's still probably 5 feet tall when they are sitting.  A truck-chassis work van could.

The high roof is going to be necessary to allow your centaur to get anywhere close to the driver's position, otherwise you're going to need some sort of conveyor system to get them in place. With a high roof, they can enter through the "trunk" doors, walk up to the front, and then sit.

In addition to the physical size requirements, these types of vans are very frequently outfitted with a variety of add-on equipment for a number of uses.  That means third-party up-fitters are used to working with them, and should be able to easily adapt some equipment to meet your centaur's needs.

Since your centaur is going to be "sitting", all-hand controls will be necessary, but that's not a problem.  We currently have [vehicle hand controls](https://www.mobilityworks.com/hand-controls/) for people without use of their legs.

Comment: Awesome! There's things here I wouldn't have thought of in a million years! Great Chris!